# Save much entity with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, save, entity

I'm working with java and hibernate, I need to save several entities at once, with a small change in them, only when I save the hibernate saves the first and deepois updates the same. Please help me!

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? deepois?

Answer (score 0):

## This is the methods from my repository!

```
 public void Salvar(Lancamento lancamento) throws SQLException {
            //insert repetitions if there is any
                    if (lancamento.isRepetir()) {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= lancamento.getNumRepeticao(); i++) {

                            this.Inserir(lancamento);

                            Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
                            data.setTime(lancamento.getData());
                            if (lancamento.getPeriodicidade().getValor() == 0) {
                                data.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                            }
                            if (lancamento.getPeriodicidade().getValor() == 1) {
                                data.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1);
                            }
                            if (lancamento.getPeriodicidade().getValor() == 2) {
                                data.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                            }
                            if (lancamento.getPeriodicidade().getValor() == 3) {
                                data.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
                            }

                            lancamento.setData(data.getTime());
                        }

                    }
                    //if no repetitions
                    else{
                        this.Inserir(lancamento);
                    }
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void Inserir(Lancamento lancamento) throws SQLException {
            this.getHibernateTemplate().persist(lancamento);
        }
```

### Here is the result

```
 // I'm sending an entity repeat twice annually

Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('SEQ_LANCAMENTO')
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        tb_lancamento
        (cl_lancamento, dt_lancamento, desc_lacamento, fp_lancamento, nr_lancamento, pe_lancamento, rp_lancamento, st_lancamento, vl_lancamento, cd_lancamento) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    update  // Here he is giving an update
        tb_lancamento 
    set
        cl_lancamento=?,
        dt_lancamento=?,
        desc_lacamento=?,
        fp_lancamento=?,
        nr_lancamento=?,
        pe_lancamento=?,
        rp_lancamento=?,
        st_lancamento=?,
        vl_lancamento=? 
    where
        cd_lancamento=?
```